# Find maximum value of list based on criteria of first element

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the following list:

```
    list={{55.1958, -0.349675}, {55.8649, -0.317977}, {55.9733, -0.31084},
{56.3041, -0.286584}, {56.3297, -0.284539}, {56.7858, -0.243529},
{56.9002, -0.232266}, {58.1689, -0.0329478}, {58.1721, -0.0322038},
{59.6201, 0.490692}, {59.9231, 0.634417}, {60.1028, 
  0.71699}, {61.5448, 0.627379}, {61.8061, 0.4619}, {61.9406, 
  0.379888}, {63.7961, 0.00405673}, {63.8918, 0.00285513}, {64.2303, 
  0.0018482}, {64.4817, 0.0026852}, {64.5854, 0.00286071}, {64.9619, 
  0.0026916}, {65.2636, 0.00266422}, {65.4107, 0.00303601}, {65.8283, 
  0.0047811}, {65.8594, 0.00496729}, {66.1707, 0.00693903}, {66.3076, 
  0.00784256}, {66.3826, 0.00832286}, {66.5637, 0.00923505}, {66.8723,
   0.0110684}, {67.0349, 0.0122277}, {67.2602, 0.0143215}, {67.3616, 
  0.0154748}, {67.5422, 0.0175274}, {67.5623, 0.0177623}, {67.7695, 
  0.0204659}, {67.8752, 0.02194}, {68.0342, 0.0241818}, {68.1368, 
  0.0256453}, {68.303, 0.028032}, {68.3994, 0.0294309}, {68.8128, 
  0.0363789}, {68.8927, 0.0378617}, {70.0613, 0.0703509}, {70.0904, 
  0.0714557}, {70.5566, 0.0897313}, {70.7156, 0.0966578}, {71.0797, 
  0.113603}, {71.1489, 0.117293}, {72.54, 0.309317}, {72.7591, 
  0.368755}, {72.8663, 0.396925}, {73.4503, 0.306532}, {74.5514, 
  0.0450008}, {74.7037, 0.0411367}, {74.9505, 0.0353007}, {74.9568, 
  0.0351677}, {75.7922, 0.0215057}, {76.0215, 0.0189822}, {76.3928, 
  0.0157741}, {76.5846, 0.0147464}, {76.7665, 0.013607}, {76.9156, 
  0.0126136}, {77.3027, 0.0100844}, {77.394, 0.0096262}, {78.0759, 
  0.00653923}, {78.1815, 0.00610426}, {79.388, 0.00480405}, {79.7775, 
  0.00461144}, {80.4616, 0.0048199}, {80.5252, 0.00504478}, {81.0225, 
  0.00812861}, {81.2425, 0.00970376}, {81.9441, 0.014958}, {81.9524, 
  0.0150288}, {82.2023, 0.0175119}, {82.2312, 0.0178397}, {82.4584, 
  0.0204348}, {82.5091, 0.0210096}, {82.7284, 0.0233184}, {82.7436, 
  0.0234685}, {83.4903, 0.0337986}, {83.5689, 0.0349307}, {83.7846, 
  0.0379793}, {83.8085, 0.0383198}, {84.0496, 0.0418432}, {84.0723, 
  0.0421832}, {84.5827, 0.0516388}, {84.6306, 0.0527725}, {84.9036, 
  0.0589444}, {85.1689, 0.0635194}, {85.8994, 0.082384}, {85.9304, 
  0.0836593}, {86.4216, 0.10509}, {86.444, 0.106238}, {86.6771, 
  0.11893}, {86.7187, 0.121329}, {88.4615, 0.923822}, {88.776, 
  0.834447}, {89.3438, 0.0264924}}
```

I want to find the (x,y) data that is the maximum based on the first element. In particular, I want to find:

1. The (x,y) data that is the maximum but lower than 60.791 based on the first element (answer would be: `{60.1028, 0.71699}`)

2.The (x,y) data that is the maximum but lower than 73.127 based on the first element (answer would be: `{72.8663, 0.396925}`)

3. The (x,y) data that is the maximum but lower than 88.611 based on the first element (answer would be: `{88.4615, 0.923822}`)

Comment: @flinty yes, you are right! I edited it. Thank you for the answer. That works great! I accepted it !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
First@MaximalBy[Select[list, #[[1]] < 60.791 &], First]
First@MaximalBy[Select[list, #[[1]] < 73.127 &], First]
First@MaximalBy[Select[list, #[[1]] < 88.611 &], First]

(* or as a function: *)
sel[data_, threshold_] := First@MaximalBy[Select[data, #[[1]] < threshold &], First]
sel[list, #] & /@ {60.791, 73.127, 88.611}
```